# Rails Active Record, limit per attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to fetch a limited number of records per an attribute. For example, if I have a model `Post` with attribute `author_id`, I want to fetch all posts, but at most 10 per author?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit`method.

Like `User.limit(10)` will get retrieve 10 users

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your author has many posts & posts belongs to author.
Then, the required code should be something similar to below:

```
authors = Author.joins(:posts)
authors.includes(:posts).each do |author|
 author.post.limit(10)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite pure AR solution, so your performance may vary:

```
Post.all.pluck(:author_id).uniq.map do |author_id|
    Post.where(author_id: author_id).limit(10)
end.flatten
```

This could be further optimized by writing some custom SQL query but that is all I can come up with at the moment.